What is the probability of solipsism?
What is the probability of solipsism?
Is there a generally accepted professional assessment of the probability, plausibility and persuasiveness of solipsism?
I would like to know:
How likely solipsism is.
How convincing solipsism is.
How plausible is solipsism.
What does professional philosophy say?
And what is it all measured in?
In percentage?

You’ve asked this question about 4 times during the last day. Thus, I’m forced to downvote for asking duplicate questions

What did you already find out from sources like https://plato.stanford.edu/?

Plausible: yes. Percentage: meaningless question.

I just couldn't find any info anywhere on the probability. I want to know what is the probability of solipsism. Perhaps Occam's razor and other heuristic tools, as well as logical analysis, create some probability that was calculated by experts.Is solipsism more likely than the existence of other minds or less likely? Maybe there are some percentages. For example, solipsism is 1%, and the existence of other minds is 99%. Thank you

1 in 8,000,000,000?

I already answered you in a comment in which I told you the probability was lower than 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003142% I might as well talk to the wall.

Okay, so what does that probability give us, even if it's 0.0000000000000000000001%? Should we reject solipsism as implausible, or believe in the existence of other minds with a slight incredulity? The low probability of solipsism means that it is false, or it simply means that solipsism is as possible as the existence of other minds, just that the chance of solipsism being true is 1 in a trillion. Because they are different things.

If this would were designed to convince you you're not the only consciousness, even though you ARE the only consciousness, do you really think we'd be trustworthy to tell you the truth about it? There's a 0% chance of Solipsism. My source?: trust me

Solipsism is interesting philosophically not because anyone thinks it is true, but because to prove it false appears to be impossible even though we all know it's false. As for your question, should we believe something with an 0.0000000000000000000001% chance to be implausible- what do you think????

The question is whether probability means:

0.000000001% means that solipsism is false because the probability is less than 50%.
Or
0.000000001% means that solipsism is as possible as the existence of other minds, just the chance that solipsism is true is very small, but in this case we will not be able to find out how we should treat solipsism because this chance just might happen to us.


Verify Solipsism using Statistics
Ha! Ha!! Ah-luv-it. Me-thinks that's a new and original one!
More seriously, I'll address your question:

What does professional philosophy say about the persuasiveness of solipsism?

By looking at it from a history-of-philosophy angle. But I am not a historian, still less a philosophy-historian.
Nowadays we have a newtool which can help such 'research'...
chatGPT
So I asked chatGPT where it starts.
And apart from an indirect reference to Parmenides the main founder of this "philosophical school" seems to be Descartes.
Aha! So now we are getting warmer.
And what do we find of Descartes+Solipsism?
IEP says this:

Solipsism is implicit in many philosophies of knowledge and mind since Descartes and any theory of knowledge that adopts the Cartesian egocentric approach as its basic frame of reference is inherently solipsistic.

There we have it — Descartes!
IEP continues:

Solipsism merits close examination because it is based upon three widely entertained philosophical presuppositions, which are themselves of fundamental and wide-ranging importance. These are: (a) What I know most certainly are the contents of my own mind—my thoughts, experiences, affective states, and so forth.; (b) There is no conceptual or logically necessary link between the mental and the physical. For example, there is no necessary link between the occurrence of certain conscious experiences or mental states and the “possession” and behavioral dispositions of a body of a particular kind; and (c) The experiences of a given person are necessarily private to that person.
These presuppositions are of unmistakable Cartesian origin, and are widely accepted by philosophers and non-philosophers alike. In tackling the problem of solipsism, one immediately grapples with fundamental issues in the philosophy of mind. However spurious the problem of solipsism per se may strike one, these latter issues are unquestionably important. Indeed, one of the merits of the entire enterprise is the extent that it reveals a direct connection between apparently unexceptionable and certainly widely-held common sense beliefs and the acceptance of solipsistic conclusions. If this connection exists and we wish to avoid those solipsistic conclusions, we shall have no option but to revise, or at least to critically review, the beliefs from which they derive logical sustenance.
In introducing “methodic doubt” into philosophy, René Descartes created the backdrop against which solipsism subsequently developed and was made to seem, if not plausible, at least irrefutable.


I'm not convinced. Not sure about the other 8,000,000,000 possible candidates. Oh! Can we include animals? Insects? Bacteria... Other planets with life... (mumble mumble recedes in distance...)

Okay, so what does that probability give us, even if it's 0.0000000000000000000001%? Should we reject solipsism as implausible, or believe in the existence of other minds with a slight incredulity? The low probability of solipsism means that it is false, or it simply means that solipsism is as possible as the existence of other minds, just that the chance of solipsism being true is 1 in a trillion. Because they are different things.

+1 I really appreciate your answer but why such name calling ("the culprit") to Descartes,  he is the founding father of ontology (as a formal philosophical study) in my perspective. He is truly an amazing thinker.

@Howwhye Heh! I was joking! The whole answer is in a lighter vein. Anyways... The offending word is removed. I could make the answer more solid and serious. But I suspect you won't like it (if I say more about Descartes  )

@Rushi I wasn't being all too serious myself, I just lowkey thought because your central philosophical alignment was probably Eastern, you probably didn't like people who promoted (are central to) the individualistic Western philosophy that was at often times branded "modern" (lead to post-modernism)
